# Creating a Loop in JavaScript/JQuery for .slideDown function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've created a quiz using:

- php (to store the answers in MySQL DB)
- html (to create radio/checkboxes and give them names, values and IDs)
- JavaScript/JQuery (to reveal the following question after the current is answered/hide and uncheck the following question if a previous one has been answered differently.

My issue however, is without realising how many different functions it would take to create this I've ended up with hundreds of lines of JavaScript/JQuery to function a 50 question quiz.

Here is a little snippet of my code to see what I'm talking about:

**Quiz JavaScript**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var par = $('#A2');
  $(par).hide();

  $('#A1Y').click(function(e) {
      $(par).slideDown('slow');

  });
    $('#A1N').click(function(e) {
      $(par).slideDown('slow');

  });
});
</script>
```

**Quiz HTML**

```
<div id="A1">
        <h5>A1</h5>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="A1" value="Yes" id="A1Y"/>
        &nbsp;Yes
        </label>
<br>
        <label>
        <input type="radio" name="A1" value="No" id="A1N"/>
        &nbsp;No
        </label>
</div>
```

The above html/JavaScript combination I have repeated for every question, however later on in the quiz some of the functions change so that if Question B1 is answered No, it will reveal question C1, but if B1 is answered Yes, it will reveal B2.

Basically, if someone were to complete all of the B section (1 to 8 - assuming they answered Yes on question B1) but then at the end changed their mind and clicked No for question B1, B2 to 8 would be unchecked, and Question C2 is then revealed. *Here is the JQuery for that*:

**JQuery**

```
$('#B1N').click(function(){
     $('#B2').hide('slow')
     .find('input:radio').each(function(){ this.checked = false; });
});


$('#B1N').click(function(){
     $('#B3').hide('slow')
     .find('input:radio').each(function(){ this.checked = false; });
});
```

And I have the above JQuery all the way up to #B8 - and then this code repeats itself for similar structured sections C, D, E, F & G.

As you can see, this is not a convenient way of coding and it just got out of hand, when more questions kept getting added to the quiz and I started wondering if there was a way to create a loop like function to contain all this information.